# xml parsing for a single string that contains spaces

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

My Android app is calling .NET web method and it returns a single string. I am using saxparser to parse a single string like:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">LOCAL NT AUTHORITY\NTLM Authentication Not in role Administrators</string>
```

and characters() function in my data handler:

```
        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        String chars = new String(ch, start, length);
        Log.v("characters", chars);
        chars = chars.trim();

        if (_inItem) {
            _data = chars;
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when I test it with webserver 1, it works ok but with webserver 2 it returns empty string.

With webserver 1, I saw characters() function is being called just once and it returns the whole string "LOCAL NT AUTHORITY\NTLM Authentication Not in role Administrators". Perfect!

But with webserver 2, charaters() function is being called multiple times and it finally returns empty string..?

```
04-20 10:09:43.161: VERBOSE/characters(405): LOCAL
04-20 10:09:43.161: VERBOSE/characters(405): NT AUTHORITY\NTLM Authentication
04-20 10:09:43.161: VERBOSE/characters(405): Not in role Administrators
04-20 10:09:43.250: VERBOSE/endElement(405): string=0
```

Is it about handling spaces? What's happening here?

I ended up changing characters() function:

```
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    String chars = new String(ch, start, length);

    if (_inItem) {
        _data += chars;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are they returning in different character encodings? Have you got print lines in the start and end tags, to make surethe XML is correct

Comment: In Internet Explorer, they are returning the same xml starting with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the sax interface is defined, there can be multiple calls to characters, its not expected that you'll get all the characters in a single element in one call. If you need the entire string in one piece, its up to your implementation to collect and concatenate them together.

Comment: Ah yes I remember now, yeah so you collect the chars with a StringBuilder perhaps in the character method, then actually build the string in the endElement() method. (as then you know it has them all by then).

Comment: @superfall Can you tell me why, in webserver 1, characters() is being called just once with the whole string?

Comment: It just down to where packet/buffer boundaries etc end up.